# Angular2 fallback route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can I configure Angular2 router to redirect me to a default route (or any other) if I go to a non existent route?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found this solution

```
{ component: HomeComponent, path: "", pathMatch: "full" },
{ component: LoginComponent, path: "/login" },
{ component: NotFoundComponent, path: "**" }
```

Comment: Thank U for giving such inforamtion, I have created subviews using **@routerconfig()** in child components and I was able to navigate using **routerLink**. For example Parent: ` #/sales`  and Childs: `#sales/asia` & `#sales/eu` , on clicking links ; child views are perfectly working. But I was not able to load `#sales/asia` initally, I have used default router option still its not working. How can I load  `#/sales/asia` initailly on loading `#sales` view?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

For redirecting the default route (`/`), see the [`Route` api docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Route-class.html). Just set the default route's `useAsDefault` parameter to `true`

For example, if you have a route defined like:

```
@RouteConfig([ {path: '/home', component: HomeCmp, name: 'Home', useAsDefault: true} ])
```

the `/` route will be re-routed to `/home`

As mentioned by the OP in his answer, to redirect all undefined routes to a certain route, use

```
@RouteConfig([ /*...,*/ {path: '/**', redirectTo: ['Home']} ])
```

Comment: Yes. I'll try to put up a working plunkr example as soon as I get to a computer. If you're having problems, it might be that the server isn't configured to route unknown routes to your `index.html` file. Try using the `HashLocationStrategy` or look up how to set your server/dev server to route unknown routes to your main html file. (though this should only appear when you set the path in the address bar directly or refresh the page). Try setting a `routerLink` to an unknown route while using `useAsDefault` and it should re-route correctly.

Comment: You're right, `useAsDefault` only works for redirecting `/` to the default route. Edited my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 7):

The router is changed to new version and now fall back routes are userd in this way.
refer :[Angular 2 route](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#)

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/member/dashboard', terminal: true },
{
  path: 'member',
  component: MemberMainComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent
    }
  ]
},
{ path: '**', component: DashboardComponent }
```